# Updating Select All/Deselect All Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

The following code works fine when selecting all checkboxes, however it uses the the input type of button.  How could i change this into an anchor (eg.  like a link) instead of an input type of button.  This needs to update to UnCheck All once all are selected.  I have tried using the innerHTML placing it within a DIV, however have not been successful.  I would be grateful for any help like always.

Many thanks

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function Check(chk)
{
if(document.myform.Check_All.value=="Check All"){
for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
chk[i].checked = true ;
document.myform.Check_All.value="UnCheck All";
}else{

for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
chk[i].checked = false ;
document.myform.Check_All.value="Check All";
}
}

// End -->
</script>
<form name="myform" action="checkboxes.asp" method="post">


<input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="1">apple<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="2">banana<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="3">pear<br>

<input type="button" name="Check_All" value="Check All" onClick="Check(document.myform.check_list)"> 



</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first thought up of a quick answer but then I noticed that this will suck pretty badly
because it's completely braindead if someone manually ticks the checkboxes.

```
<form name="myform" action="checkboxes.asp" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="1">apple<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="2">banana<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="3">pear<br>
</form>

<div id="checker">Check All</div>

<script type ="text/javascript">
//The toggle code for the div itself
$("#checker").bind("click", function() {
    var toggleState = !! jQuery.data(this, "togglestate");

    $(document.myform.check_list).each(function() {
    this.checked = !toggleState;
    });


    $(this).text(toggleState ? "Check All" : "UnCheck All");
    jQuery.data(this, "togglestate", !toggleState);
});

//Keep track of manual ticking of the checkboxes
//- if all checkboxes are ticked manually, change to uncheck all
//- if all checkboxes are unticked manualy, change to check all

$(document.myform).delegate("input[name=check_list]", "change", function() {
    var curState, prevState, fullStateChange = true;

    //Iterate through the checkboxes to see if all are unticked or if all are ticked
    $(document.myform.check_list).each(function() {
    curState = this.checked;

    if (prevState != null && prevState !== curState) {
        fullStateChange = false;
    }

    prevState = curState;
    });

    //Return as some were ticked and some were not
    if (!fullStateChange) {
    return;
    }

    $("#checker").data("togglestate", curState).text(!curState ? "Check All" : "UnCheck All");

});

//React to initial state of the checkbuttons
$(document.myform.check_list).trigger( "change" );
</script>
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/rBaUM/2/

Comment: This is fantastic!  I have one question though.  Say if i have multiple fields that require this checkbox, how can i set the name of the field (in this instance its check_list) to work on different checkboxes?  This will save me re-writing the code for each checkbox (specifying different div - checker1, checker2 etc) and input names

Comment: @skippy, by using basic programming concepts like loops, arrays and objects. :P Too tired to refactor it :(

Comment: Oh okay, Apologies im very new to jquery! I'll figure it out.  Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @skippy in stackoverflow you thank by giving votes and accepting answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function Check(chk){
 var checkedVal = document.getElementById("Check_All");

 if(checkedVal.innerHTML=="Check All"){
  for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
  chk[i].checked = true ;
  checkedVal.innerHTML = "UnCheck All";
 }else{
  for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
   chk[i].checked = false ;
   checkedVal.innerHTML = "Check All";
 }
}
</script>
<form name="myform" action="checkboxes.asp" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="1">apple<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="2">banana<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="3">pear<br>

<a href="javascript:;" id="Check_All" onClick="Check(document.myform.check_list); return false">Check All</a>
</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was after.  I cn readily use this in my script, and also call this function for different fields that use multiple checkboxes.  One question though does innerHTML work on different browsers?  Thanks for your help

Comment: @skippy, yes many browsers fully support the innerHTML property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you're asking for, but using non-button is like

```
<div onclick="Check(document.myform.check_list)">Check All</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael.  Yes this is close to what I'm after, however as soon as you click the div (that is labelled "Check All", I want this text then to update to "UnCheck All" (or something similar).  Do I need to use the InnerHTML attribute for this to change within the javascript function?  In addition, as its plain text within the div the user would not know whether you can select this that is why i was going to place in a HTML link anchor.  Can this be place in the <a href...

Comment: Yes, you need to use `.innerHTML` of `div` object to update contents. You can use `a` for this purpose as well, but you can also style the `div` or whatever element you want to use.